# How can I count my followers in django template?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

This is my second time when i am asking this question again because i guess first time this question didn't reach to the people who can tell me the solution of this question. Well here i just want to count followers and following, but i don't know how can i count tell and show them in a profile detail template. I don't understand how can i find followers and following respectively with a single follower field which is mentioned in model.py. If anybody know answers than please answer. I shall be very thankful to you.

models.py.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    follower = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name ='is_following',blank=True,)
    avatar = models.ImageField(("Avatar"), upload_to='displays', default = '1.jpg',height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=None,blank = True)
    create_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True,null=True)
   
    objects = ProfileManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username}'
```

view.py(profile detail view)

```
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(UserProfileDetailView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        user = context['user']

        '''#Trying with this but it is not working i guess this is wrong way to this but i am not sure!!'''
        allprofile = UserProfile.objects.all()
        followers = 0

        for u in allprofile.follower:
            if u == user.userprofile:
                followers+=1
        context['followers']=followers
        return context
```

if more detail is require than tell me in a comment session. I will update my question with that detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can count the number of followers by accessing the `ManyToManyField` relation in reverse with the [**`related_name=…`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.related_name) with:

```
followers = user.is_following.count()
```

or if you want to count the number of `User`s in the `follower` relation (so in reverse), you query with:

```
# opposite direction
followers = user.userprofile.follower.count()
```

Comment: Umm will this count followers and followings respectively ?

Comment: @AhmedYasin: yes. But it is a bit unclear in what direction your followers are stored. If *A* is following *B*, then is *A* an element of `B.followers`, or vice-versa?

Comment: Yes this is actually giving right data and i have ask one question where i have ask that how can i give following boost for every new user and you gave me answer. `def create_profile(sender, created, instance,**kwargs):
    if created:
        pk_range = UserProfile.objects.count()
        if pk_range > 1:
            k1, k2 = sample(range(pk_range), 2)
            f1 = UserProfile.objects.all()[k1]
            f2 = UserProfile.objects.all()[k2]
          
            userprofile = UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
            userprofile.follower.add(f1.user_id, f2.user_id)`

Comment: this function is actually increasing following of instance user , it suppose to give followers not following

Comment: then it is `instance.is_following.add(f1, f2)`. instead of `userprofile.follower.add(...)`.

Comment: do i have to remove this  `userprofile = UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)             userprofile.follower.add(f1.user_id, f2.user_id`

Comment: @AhmedYasin: not the `UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance) `.

Comment: I have a question that I am actually wanting to build a notification system with Django, When someone follows to some other people than they get noticed or when someone like other people posts than those people also get notified. I just want to know which will be the best approach for building this notification system with Django framework.

Comment: let me add that if you want to show the count in a template, the right usage is:

{{ user.is_following.count }} followers